# hiding view added on window

Tags: iphone, uiwindow

As per the requirement the top navigatiobar should not move when view moves back and forth....
so I added the topbar on the instance of `UIWindow`....but when I open the camera this topbar also appears there....Is there any way to hide this top bar.
I hid the default navigation bar and instead using the `imageView` object.
I created a function which removes it from `superView` but its not working.

Code::

```
UIImageView *imgViewNavigatioBar=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgViewNavigatioBar.frame=CGRectMake(self.window.bounds.origin.x, self.window.bounds.origin.y, kAppWidth, 100.0);
    imgViewNavigatioBar.image=[UIImage imageNamed:kNavigationBarImage];
    [[self window] addSubview:imgViewNavigatioBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding the imageview, set a tag for that imageview as follows.

```
UIImageView *imgViewNavigatioBar=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgViewNavigatioBar.tag = 100;
...
```

Then, where ever you want to hide that imageview from any class, do as follows.

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView*)[window viewWithTag:100];
iv.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: for(UIView *view in [self window].subviews)
    {
        
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        else if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        else
        {
        
        }
    }

it is working for me for now...thanks!